# Usage of "sei" in old and modern german?

Tags: etymology, history

I have noticed in both [commercial folk music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R1v8wpScKNI) as well as older texts it seems very often that constructions with "sei" (alter sein/ist?) are being frequently used. Meanwhile I have almost never seen it in (my) homework assignments, newspaper text, TV or from other modern sources.

Is it still part of the german language?

Example of some old text where it occurs:

[image]
my attempt at reading (lol):

Anschaulicher, als durch dieses Gleichniß vom menschlichen Leibe, läßt sich gewiß nicht zeigen, wie notwendig es für das Gedeihen einer jeden gesellschaftlichen Verbindung **sei**, daß deren Glieder stets in Eintracht mit einander bleiben...

---

**Edit:**
OMG here is also word Leib as in Leibler(?) (Kullback-Leibler Divergenz für die Mathe-freaks)

Is it also an example of Hochdeutsch or something else?

Comment: It's still used by mathematicians - does this count as _modern usage_?

Comment: @Marzipanherz I suppose it does. Any reference would be welcome.

Comment: Sorry, I can't listen to *volksdümmliche Musik* longer than 10 seconds. Btw: What you can see and hear in this video is NOT (I repeat: IT IS **NOT**) traditional music. This is modern commercial music, composed and produced to earn money. It developed from traditional music, but it no longer has to do anything with real traditional music. Calling the music from your video *traditional* is like claiming *hip hop* would be the same as *soul music*. It developed from three, but it no longer has anything in common with it.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast ah okay, thanks for your input. Impressive to say for sure with less than 10 seconds to listen ;)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast I changed to commercial folk music instead.

Comment: @mathreadler: I am singing in a classical concert choir, but 20 years ago I was in a different choir, and there we also performed real traditional music, also together with musicians who played traditional instruments like the [Hackbrett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammered_dulcimer), the [Steirische Harmonika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steirische_Harmonika) (mind the keys!) or the alpine harp. Maybe you never heard real traditional alpine Volksmusik. Here is a playlist of real alpine Volksmusik: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fjgifWPUbmk&index=1&list=PL6A45FA22B3B94F00

Comment: Hearing 10 seconds of *volkstümliche Musik* and then knowing that this is not *Volksmusik* is like listening to 10 seconds of *hip hop* and knowing, that this is not *soul music*. Also compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volksmusik and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkstümliche_Musik

Comment: It was not necessary to turn on the sound to recognize what kind of music it is ;) Also, we were told the title.

Comment: https://dwds.de/wb/Leib

Comment: @CarstenS it *could* have been a trick title with todesmetallsymphonien überall ;)

Comment: First word is "Anschaulicher" btw.

Comment: @Javatasse of course, that makes sense. It's not totally easy to read these hieroglyphs :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, your two examples show two totally different forms of "sein".

The *sei* from the folk music song is simply a dialect version of the infinitive *sein*, which is shortened to "sei" in lots of (mainly southern) dialects. These dialects are still very much alive in German.

The text example shows a sort of "reported speech". It is actually hochdeutsch, but *sei* in that example is **Konjunktiv I**. This usage is a bit archaic, as we probably wouldn't use Konjunktiv with "zeigen" today - with other verbs of expression (like "sagen", for example), the usage of Konjunktiv I *sei* in reported speech is totally common.

Comment: Ah, that is very fascinating two different sources of sei, one dialectal and one historic.

Comment: Historic is not quite right, see my amends

Answer (score 7):

I have not turned on the sound, but I doubt that there is anything traditional about that song. Anyway, *sei* in it is merely a dialect version of *sein*. On the other hand, the *sei* in the quoted text is Konjunktiv I. That form is stil alive and well, but I do indeed see no reason for Konjunktiv in contemporary grammar in that place.

Comment: Ah, so which dialects use sei instead of sein? Any sources would be appreciated as well.

Comment: @mathreadler The song title you've linked _"A Lausbua muss er sei"_ is Bavarian dialect. In high German this would read as _"... muss er sein"_.

Answer (score 3):

In the modern spoken language, the konjunktiv present (as in the form *sei)* is rarely used except in Switzerland and Vorarlberg, see [indirekte Rede « atlas-alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-3/f08e/).

It is therefore not surprising that modern texts use the konjunktiv present less frequently than older texts.

As the others have already pointed out, the song you have linked has a dialectal form of *sein.*

## Why?

The reason for the decreasing usage has to do with the forms. The konjunktiv present is often not distinguishable from the indicative present. In that sense, the konjunktiv present is going the way the indicative preterit has gone in Southern German: it is disappearing because it has merged with another form.

In the following forms, konjunktiv and indicative present have completely merged:

- ich singe
- wir singen
- sie singen

The only distinction between konjunktiv and indicative present in the following forms is a [schwa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa), which is easily lost in speech:

- du sing**e**st – singst
- ihr sing**e**t – singt

Consequently, the only form with a reliable distinction between konjunktiv and indicative present is the third person singular:

- er/sie/es sing**e** – sing**t**

On the other hand, dialects in Switzerland and Vorarlberg have conserved a more complete konjunktiv present paradigm than other dialects or Standard German. In Bernese German – as an example for a Swiss German dialect – the entire paradigm is distinct:

- i sing**i** – sing**e**
- du sing**i**sch – singsch
- är/si/äs sing**i** – sing**t**
- mir sing**i** – sing**e**
- dihr sing**i**t – sing**e**t
- si sing**i** – si sing**e**

Comment: Wow Bern dialect seems very unique. är/si/äs, mir, dihr I think I have never seen.

Comment: It is not all that unique. Other Swiss German dialects share most/all of these forms.

Comment: That is weird, maybe I have simply not heard enough Schweizerdeutsch to know what it sounds like.